# Selfhost security issue?

Tags: servicestack

When using selfhost .Net Core 2.x, all the build artifacts are statically served by default, since the default directory is the same place as the binary/exe.

This means if one knows the names of the dlls, they can just request
them at /Whatever.dll, or they can also get any config files by name,
i.e. appSettings.

If you change things so that that the root directory is different or that directory is not in the VFS, /metadata stops working.

Is it possible to have /metadata work, but not allow the service's dlls etc to be statically served?

I have tried restricting the paths.  This will keep settings / dlls / exes from serving, but the /metadata page will come up completely blank.

Answer (score 1):

The `/metadata` page isn't related to the static file directory location, you may have caused a Startup Exception that's impacted how it works. If you can put together a stand-alone project on GitHub which shows the issue I can investigate.

Only extensions in `Config.AllowFileExtensions` can be served, you can remove `.dll` from being served with:

```
Config.AllowFileExtensions.Remove("dll");
```

`.exe` aren't servable by default, if you can download them you might be downloading them with .NET Core's static file handler instead.

It's common practice to have the WebRoot outside of the project root which for .NET Core is typically `/wwwroot`.

Comment: thanks -- one thing I found on selfhosting, is that the VFS seems to be setup to serve from the app's startup directory, no matter what WebHostPhysicalPath is set to.  I might be doing something wrong, but I was setting it via SetConfig() in the Configure method.

Comment: @cmac it's because selfhost is the [bare bones configuration](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost/blob/master/MyApp/Program.cs#L19) without .NET Core's default conventions [wrapped in WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web/blob/4cea171f8a1b8db097ddba29529aa7f2e8cb310a/MyApp/Program.cs#L21).

Answer (score 0):

edit: Updated suggestion to remove the badness.

What I ended up doing at first was to add a `.UseWebRoot()` onto the
builder, then later switched from the selfhost ServiceStack template
to the web template per Mythz's suggestion.  The web template was
set up in a way that solved my problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't modify the VFS like this, [change .NET Core's WebRoot instead](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web/blob/4cea171f8a1b8db097ddba29529aa7f2e8cb310a/MyApp/Program.cs#L21), it's expected for the FileSystem in VirtualFileSources to be configured to WebRoot. You're likely better off starting with the [web](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web) template. All .NET Core Apps are SelfHosting Web Apps, the difference between selfhost vs web is selfhost has less deps and starts with no .NET Core configuration whereas `web` project template is the empty template with .NET Core conventions.

Comment: Great point and much better approach.  Looks like I over thought it, and didn't understand what the templates were really setup for.  I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.  Definitely understand things way better now and am doing as you suggest.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to remove this suggestion? It's providing the wrong solution/guidance, thx.